# How to get the JSON array as respone from asp.net core web api

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

Hi guys i am trying to pull data from multiple tables in one SQL query using LINQ and Entity Framework. I need to get the details from the database.There are multiple regions.

1) Get all the regions.
2) get all project in the regions.
3) get all the sections in the projects.

I need to get all project details from each region based on region id.

```
public partial class Regions
    {
        public Regions()
        {
            Projects = new HashSet<Projects>();
            RegionUserRelation = new HashSet<RegionUserRelation>();
        }

        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string RegionName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string RegionFullname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int RegionTypeId { get; set; }
        public string RegionMisc { get; set; }

        public RegionType RegionType { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RegionUserRelation> RegionUserRelation { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Projects
    {
        public Projects()
        {
            Sections = new HashSet<Sections>();
        }

        public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
        public string ProjectDesc { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int EpsgId { get; set; }

        public Epsg Epsg { get; set; }
        public Regions Region { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Sections> Sections { get; set; }
    }


public partial class Sections
    {
        public Sections()
        {
            Flights = new HashSet<Flights>();
        }

        public Guid SectionId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string SectionName { get; set; }
        public string SectionDesc { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

        public Projects Project { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Flights> Flights { get; set; }
    }
```

Expected output is :

```
{ "Regions" : 
  [ { 
        "region_id" : "2012",
        "region_name" : "region1",
        "region_fullname" : "21700",
        "region_type" : "MERCH",
            "Projects" : [ 
               {     "project_id" : 2341,
                     "project_name " : "DXY",
                     "project_code " : "21700",
                     "sections" : [
                                { "section_id" : 4356,
                                "section_name" : sec_name,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis},
                                { "section_id" : 476,
                                "section_name" : sec_name2,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis2},
                                { "section_id" : 908,
                                "section_name" : sec_name3,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis3}
                            ]
                },
            "Projects" : [ 
               {     "project_id" : 1321,
                     "project_name " : "Proj_2",
                     "project_code " : "01700",
                     "sections" : [
                                { "section_id" : 4356,
                                "section_name" : sec_name,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis},
                                { "section_id" : 476,
                                "section_name" : sec_name2,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis2},
                                { "section_id" : 908,
                                "section_name" : sec_name3,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis3}
                            ]
                },
            ]
  },
  { 
        "region_id" : "2013",
        "region_name" : "region3",
        "region_fullname" : "21330",
        "region_type" : "MERCH",
            "Projects" : [ 
               {     "project_id" : 2341,
                     "project_name " : "DXY",
                     "project_code " : "21700",
                     "sections" : [
                                { "section_id" : 4356,
                                "section_name" : sec_name,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis},
                                { "section_id" : 476,
                                "section_name" : sec_name2,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis2},
                                { "section_id" : 908,
                                "section_name" : sec_name3,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis3}
                            ]
                },
            "Projects" : [ 
               {     "project_id" : 1321,
                     "project_name " : "Proj_2",
                     "project_code " : "01700",
                     "sections" : [
                                { "section_id" : 4356,
                                "section_name" : sec_name,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis},
                                { "section_id" : 476,
                                "section_name" : sec_name2,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis2},
                                { "section_id" : 908,
                                "section_name" : sec_name3,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis3}
                            ]
                },
            ]
  },
  { 
        "region_id" : "2012",
        "region_name" : "region2",
        "region_fullname" : "24300",
        "region_type" : "MERCH",
            "Projects" : [ 
               {     "project_id" : 2341,
                     "project_name " : "DXY",
                     "project_code " : "21700",
                     "sections" : [
                                { "section_id" : 4356,
                                "section_name" : sec_name,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis},
                                { "section_id" : 476,
                                "section_name" : sec_name2,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis2},
                                { "section_id" : 908,
                                "section_name" : sec_name3,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis3}
                            ]
                },
            "Projects" : [ 
               {     "project_id" : 1321,
                     "project_name " : "Proj_2",
                     "project_code " : "01700",
                     "sections" : [
                                { "section_id" : 4356,
                                "section_name" : sec_name,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis},
                                { "section_id" : 476,
                                "section_name" : sec_name2,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis2},
                                { "section_id" : 908,
                                "section_name" : sec_name3,
                                "section_description" : sec_dis3}
                            ]
                },
            ]
  },
] }
```

I have tried this one but it gives only one record for the region. i need all the region and all the project from the regions

```
IList<Regions> ches = entities.Regions.Include
                        (c => c.Projects).ToList();
                    return Ok(ches);
```

output

```
[{"regionId":1,"regionName":"Mitte","regionFullname":"Region Mitte","regionTypeId":1,"regionMisc":"","regionType":null,"projects":[{"projectId":"9dd284be-004d-42ee-8e21-3acbb240c488","projectName":"EÜ Stockstadt","projectCode":"B-MI01007P","projectDesc":"","regionId":1,"epsgId":32632,"epsg":null
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried this one but it gives only one record for the region. i need all the region and all the project from the regions

Be sure that your database contains more than one record.

*Model:*

```
public partial class Regions
{
    public Regions()
    {
        Projects = new HashSet<Projects>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RegionFullname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int RegionTypeId { get; set; }
    public string RegionMisc { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Projects> Projects { get; set; }
}

public partial class Projects
{
    public Projects()
    {
        Sections = new HashSet<Sections>();
    }
    [Key]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDesc { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public Regions Region { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Sections> Sections { get; set; }
}

public partial class Sections
{
    [Key]
    public Guid SectionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string SectionName { get; set; }
    public string SectionDesc { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    public Projects Project { get; set; }
}
```

*Controller:*

From your expected json,you also want to load the `Sections` model which is related to `Projects`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;

    public TestsController(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Tests
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Regions>> GetTest()
    {

        IList<Regions> ches = _context.Regions.Include
                    (c => c.Projects).ThenInclude(c=>c.Sections).ToList();
        return Ok(ches);
    }
}
```

*Startup.cs:*

For asp.net core 2.2:

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
             options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

For asp.net core 3.x:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Result:
[image]